# how to find combinations of numbers in python list that sum up to a given number in n combinations?

Tags: python, for-loop, idioms

**Question I am attempting**

Function Description

Complete the bonetrousle function in the editor below. It should return an array of integers.

bonetrousle has the following parameter(s):

n: the integer number of sticks to buy
k: the integer number of box sizes the store carries
b: the integer number of boxes to buy

**Edit:**

- The function takes in *n* as the number of sphagetti sticks to summed up from all the boxes bought by Papyrus.
- *b* is the number of boxes that will be purchased by Papyrus and then all the sphagetti in them will be added up to form *n*
- *k* will be the total boxes in the store each containing and increasing number of sphagetti for instance 8 boxes will be in the order of 1 box == 1 sphagetti , 2 boxes == sphagetti ... 8th box.

if the number *n* of boxes required by Papyrus are more compared to those in stock, then you return -1.

*I hope this clarifies the question some more*

Also this question can be better understood via HackerRack 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bonetrousle/problem

If there is a solution, print a single line of distinct space-separated integers where each integer denotes the numbers of noodles in each box that Papyrus must purchase.
If there are multiple possible solutions, you can print any one of them. Do not print any leading or trailing spaces or extra newlines.

Sample Input

- 4
- 12 8 3
- 10 3 3
- 9 10 2
- 9 10 2

Sample Output

- 2 3 7
- -1
- 5 4
- 1 8

**This is My Solution **

It should work on the first test case but I know I haven't put b(number of boxes skeleton wants to buy) to good use because I am confused about how to go about it.

```
def bonetrousle(n, k, b):
    # list the range for the store boxes {done}
    # find if the number of boxes required by skeleton are accessible from the store
    # find a combination that gives me the number of sphagetti required by skeleton
    inventory=[item for item in range(1,k+1)]
    list_of_outcome=[]
    # if sum of the items in the store is greater than the number of 
    # individual sphagetti's wanted, this means,is possible to get
    # what skeleton came looking for
    if sum(inventory)>n:
        if b==2:
            for i in inventory:
                for j in inventory:
                    if i+j==n:
                            list_of_outcome.append("{}{}".format(
                                i,j
                            ))
        else:
            for i in inventory:
                for j in inventory:
                    for k in inventory:
                        if i+j+k==n:
                            list_of_outcome.append("{}{}{}".format(
                                i,j,k
                            ))
    else:
        return ("-1")
    if list_of_outcome!=[]:
        return ((random.choice(list_of_outcome)).strip())
```

```
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer
Input (stdin)
Download
4
12 8 3
10 3 3
9 10 2
9 10 2
Your Output (stdout)
3 5 4
- 1
8 1
8 1

Expected Output
Download
2 3 7
-1
5 4
1 8
```

So, I really need your help with automating the for loops or any alternative solution because I know many for loops consume so much space and time.

Comment: As it stands, it is not a good question. It's too long and confusing. Please rework it to make more clear a) what the program is exactly supposed to do; b) what you have already tried.

Comment: Hi @ErichKitzmueller, I edited the question, My solution is attached too. For better understanding of the problem please read through the edits or kindly help me visit the hacker rank problem I am trying to solve https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bonetrousle/problem